# AJAX/PHP When checkbox checked - sending data row from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm new with ajax and php, please help me solve this :)

I have a html table with multiple checkboxes. How can I do something like this with ajax (with no refreshing page):

- when checkbox is checked then automatically adding existing data row with specific ID (for example id=3) from mysql tableXXX to tableYYY

This is my example checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if (in_array(2, $client['variables'])) {
        echo " checked ";
 }?> id="<?php echo $key ?>_2" name="<?php echo $key ?>_2" class="chbox" value="">
```

I do not know if I explained it well, I hope I do :)

Comment: can you link some code?

Comment: Added my example input checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you are looking for:

Html:

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="YES" id="yes">
   <label for="yes">YES</label>
</div>

<div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="NO" id="no">
   <label for="no">NO</label>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
   //remember to add jquery lib
   $( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
     $( "#message" ).html( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
   });
```